# How do I remove funmoods from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, google-chrome-extensions

I was installing vlc video player. But accidentally, I ended up installing the funmoods toolbar app too. How do you get rid of it?

Answer (score 4):

Did [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYihd7GU1EU) work for you when you searched for it?

Written description from [Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jJ5tMzhCPjw) is:

> To remove Funmoods from Google Chrome
>
> 1. First of all go to Control Panel, then Programs and Features for Windows 7.Look for "Funmoods" and uninstall it.
> 2. Open a Chrome browser window, Left-click the spanner (or wrench if you use the American name), top right of the browser window.
> 3. Move cursor down to "Tools".Left-click, "Extensions". On the left under basics left-click "Basics", beside the "Homepage" section, if
>      you find "Funmoods" here, delete it, and for now, above this, left
>      click, "Use The New Tab" Page and you are finished on this bit.
> 4. Now look down the "Basics" page for the "Search" section and left-click, "Manage Search Engines". If you don't find the "Search" sections, find the "settings" section and that should bring you to the "Manage Search Engines" section.
> 5. Under "Default search options", hover your curser on the "Funmoods" entry and an x should appear to the right edge of it. 
>      Left-click the x and it should remove it from the list.
> 6. Finally, Just check that your search results are no longer being given by "Funmoods".

Answer (score 2):

Have latest version of Chrome. There is no Speed Dial or Fun Dial to uninstall. Just go to Settings. Where it says On Start Up, click select pages. It should be there. Just X it out. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only method I found to remove Funmoods at start up.

- Click on the "wrench" at top right. Open "Settings."
- Locate "On Start Up." You will see blue "Set Pages" click it.
- A list of start up items will be displayed.
- At the right of Funmoods a "X" will appear as mouse moves over it.
- Click the "X" to remove Funmoods.
- Then click OK. It's GONE.

Source: http://dwaynesthisandthat.us

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling the Funmoods extension from Chrome you also have to uninstall the Speed Dial or Fun Dial extension to prevent Funmoods from loading when you open a new tab.