# remove start.funmoods search from chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome-extensions

I post this with much trepidation after my [baptism by fire recently](https://superuser.com/questions/440723/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-system-power-downs), and knowing that this question has been [asked and answered already](https://superuser.com/questions/437604/how-do-i-remove-funmoods-from-chrome).

My problem is that I cannot seem to remove `start.funmoods` as the default search engine when I type into the omnibox in Chrome - I have followed the instruction in the answer to the previous question on this topic. In particular:

1. I deleted funmods using the control panel -> add/remove programs
2. Under wrench-tools-extensions funmods is not mentioned
3. Under wrench-settings-manage search engines, there is nothing listed at all.
4. Restarted chrome and rebooting have not helped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove funmoods from Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/437604/how-do-i-remove-funmoods-from-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve this by uninstalling Chrome and re-installing it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the wrench icon.
2. Go to **Settings**.
3. Under the **Search** section click on **Manage Search Engines**.
4. Delete all search engines under **Other Search Engines**, and the ones you don't need under **Default search settings**.
5. Set Google, Yahoo or Bing as your default search engine by hovering over one of them and clicking **Make Default**.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned (point 3 in my post) there is nothing listed at all under "manage search engines"

Comment: If you don't see anything at all, try manually adding Google. You should see a text field that says "Add new search engine." Type a name for it along with your preferred keyword. Use this for the URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=%s

Comment: Thank you again. I have just tried what you suggest. I wanted to post an screencapture but I don't have enough reputation :(  When I do this, three purple boxes appear just under "Other search engines", I typed "Google" in the first two and what you wrote for the third one and then clicked on OK. The window then disappeared and when I went back to through Wrench-Settings-Manage Search engines, it is all blank again :( and funmoods still comes up when I type in the omnibox